# Is there a way in VSCode to find all variables of a certain type

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I want to find all variables of a certain go struct type I have created across my whole project. Maybe there is a VSCode extension that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on a struct and then click on 'Find all references' you can find all references to that struct. You might need the Go extension installed for this to work.

Comment: You can also Crtl+Click on the type to view every reference.